# Nonparametric way to perform ANOVA of linear mixed model and power calcualtion

Tags: r, anova, mixed-models, resampling, random-effects

I have a small data where there are 3 groups (A,B,C) and 5 participants from each group. All of those participants are measured 6 times on each of 7 different exams, so each participant get 6*7=42 scores in total. A simple linear mixed model was built `mylmm<-lmer(score ~1+group+exam+group*exam+(1|participant), data = mydata)`. I could obtain the anova results and post-hoc pairwise comparison for group, exam, and interaction of them using `anova(mylmm)` and multiple comparison function.

However, the data is very small (only 5 participants) and residual of `mylmm` is not normal, so the power is insufficient. I am aware of robust mixed model using `robustlmm` and residual bootstrap mixed model using `lmeresampler`. However, I am unable to perform anova and multiple comparisons using these methods. Could anyone help me with the following questions? It is really appreciated.

1. Is there a method and available R package to perform bootstrap anova (and post-hoc comparisons) of linear mixed model?
2. Is it still necessary to calculate the power of the bootstrap or nonparametric anova? If so, how to calculate the power?
3. I was able to use `simr` with methods anova to calculate power of testing group, exam, and the interaction for a `lme` model object. Also, can `simr` also be used to find power of post hoc pairwise comparisons or `emmeans` should be used? Thanks

Comment: "[the] residual of `mylmm` is not normal, so the power is insufficient': this is a non sequitur.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more *why* you are "... unable to perform anova and multiple comparisons using these methods"? `lmeresampler` seems like a natural way to do bootstrapping ...

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker. I just don't know how to put the anova of the mixed model into  the place of model in ```bootstrap``` and ```bootstrap_pval```. I thought the model in the function could only be the mixed model and so it only returns the results of the mixed model in terms of the estimates of slopes.

Comment: I think maybe one possible solution is the aligned ranks transformation anova?

Comment: Are your scores maybe ordinal? Should you possibly use ordinal regression instead of looking for robust regression approaches?

Comment: @Roland, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, the response is continuous but far away from normal and no tranformation works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is slightly deep statistically.  There are two basic approaches to resampling-based inference:

- *bootstrapping* (parametric or nonparametric) simulates the sampling distribution of desired quantities, from which you can compute *confidence intervals*. (You can also compute two-tailed p-values by inverting the confidence interval, which comes out to `prob_lt_0 = mean(bootsamp<0); p_val = 2*min(prob_lt_0, 1-prob_lt_0)`.)  Post-hoc comparisons are a little more complicated because they involve not just tests of comparisons, but also some kind of multiple comparisons correction (Tukey, etc.)
- *permutation tests* simulate the sampling distributions of test statistics under the null hypothesis, from which we can get p-values.

*Parametric* bootstrapping is a convenient way of resampling, especially if we have complicated grouping structures (spatial/temporal or crossed random effects) which make resampling independent groups difficult, or if we are assessing a GLMM where residual bootstrapping doesn't work. However, it assumes that the model is 'correct', which fails here because you don't want to rely on the Normality of the conditional distribution.

```r
library(lmerTest)
library(lmeresampler)

ss <- transform(sleepstudy, oddsub = factor((as.numeric(Subject) %% 2 == 1)))
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + oddsub + (Days | Subject), ss)

set.seed(101)
boot1 <- reb_bootstrap(fm1,
                       .f = fixef,
                       B = 1000,
                       reb_type = 2)

## not sure why reb_bootstrap seems to ignore the .f specification?
## but we get something useful anyway

confint(boot1, type = "perc")
## 1 beta1   253.   232.    273.  perc   0.95
## 2 beta2    10.5    7.24   13.5 perc   0.95
## 3 beta3    -3.56 -32.3    26.0 perc   0.95

 
pval <- function(x) { plt0 <- mean(x<0); 2*min(plt0, 1-plt0) }
apply(boot1$replicates[,1:3], 2, pval)
## beta1 beta2 beta3 
## 0.000 0.000 0.802
```

You can do a permutation test, but you have to do the test one term at a time, by comparing nested models (e.g. the full model vs. a model without the effect of `Days`):

```r
library(predictmeans)
fm0 <- update(fm1, . ~ . - Days)
p1 <- permlmer(fm0, fm1)
```

```
Data: ss
Models:
lmer0: Reaction ~ oddsub + (Days | Subject)
lmer1: Reaction ~ Days + oddsub + (Days | Subject)
      npar    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq) Perm-p
lmer0    6 1787.4 1806.6 -887.70   1775.4                            
lmer1    7 1765.9 1788.2 -875.94   1751.9 23.537  1 1.2256e-06  0.003
```

For power, I would probably just do the analysis assuming normality and then treat it as a slightly optimistic estimate; power analyses are always guesses/approximations anyway.

PS part of the reason that people are suggesting other options (robust LMM, ordinal models, etc.) is that these are kind of a nuisance.

Comment: Really appreciate it @BenBolker. Thank you for the suggestion on the power analysis. Is there any paper that I could refer to for this power analysis? The idea of using permutation on the nested models is a good alternative, but can it be used for post-hoc comparisons too? Thanks.

Comment: For the bootstrapping, I see many demonstrations using bootstrap.lmerMod along with bootstrap_pvals (I also understand the potential issue for testing interactions with bootstrap_pvals). Any difference by using reb_bootstrap? Lastly, it doesn't seem either bootstrap_pvals (as I tried) or your bootstrap provides p-value for each term of anova like ```anova.lmerModLmerTest``` would do, so it cannot be simply done in ```lmeresampler```?

Comment: It looks like `bootstrap()` is a wrapper for the different bootstrap types (so `bootstrap(..., type = "reb", reb_type = 2)` would be equivalent to my code above). I haven't thought carefully about how `bootstrap_pvals` works, but it's similar to the `predictmeans::permlmer` example I gave, where you have to pick a particular nested model to compare against. In my code above (the `pval()` function) I showed how to get p-values for all parameters from bootstrap results.

Comment: I didn't show post-hoc comparisons because it would be harder to think about how to extend that to the permutation/bootstrap case (because, as I said in my answer, it involves multiple-comparisons correction as well as pairwise comparisons).

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker. Could you briefly clarify when reb should be used? It seems the res and case options are also suggested in other similar questions posted on  stackoverflow. Thank you.